# Reusing the same instance of a widget in a ListView

Tags: flutter, dart

At first — I have a widget, it contains and plays a specific animation which state cannot be saved or interrupted because animation data comes from a web server permanently and this stream is important.

Second — I have a ListView.builder with 'infinite' list of Cards (simple cards, doesn't important in this situation, **app's screen contains 5 of them at the same time**).

The problem is: is it possible to set given animated widget on every 10-th position of the ListView using the same instance of it in order to save it's animation state and not recreate animated widget every time? It must be the same widget, the animation must continue — one widget's instance on the screen at the time.

I tried to use a Stack with the animated widget wrapped with Offstage widget on the upper layer and the ListView with 'gaps' on every 10-th position. So Animated widget lives permanently and when it goes out of the screen I 'turn it off' with Offstage. And when it should appear on scroll I 'switch it on' with Offstage. But it is very difficult to position animated widget and synchronize its position with a scroll position of the ListView. For this purpose I use a GlobalKey for every 'gap' in the ListView, define it's Render Rectangle to position my Animated widget on/in the given gap.

Any ideas to solve this task more elegant? Maybe it is possible to make some 'deep copy' or 'singleton' or keep it alive (somehow) in the ListView or use some slivers, and reuse the same instance of it again and again when it appears?

Comment: thats usually how instagram feed looks like, you will need to use a listview inside another one to achieve the expectation. having them at an interval difference-of 10 will remove your problem of positioning animated widget and synchronising its position with a scroll position of the list.

Comment: simply pass your animation state to a custom `StatelessWidget` constructir

Comment: @pskink I'm afraid this is impossible by design.

Comment: @LohitRachakonda good point about positioning, but it doesn't solve the main problem — instance reusing.

Comment: What you mean by that? What design?

Comment: @pskink it is impossible to get, pass or interrupt animation state. It must be the same widget all the time.

Comment: you don't have to interrupt anything - post your widgets code to see how you are using your animation state

Comment: and it does not have to be the same widget, for example linear progress bar uses a brand new widget each time the progress changes

Comment: @pskink 'animated widget' contains native channel with a two side streaming connection. I repeat it's state can't be saved or passed.

Comment: so it s a broken design, you need to decouple your presentation layer from data model, as I said, post your code to see how it works

Comment: @pskink i'm afraid I can't post widget's code. It uses a commercial package which implements native platform channels — this code is very hard to understand and it is not safe to manipulate it.

Comment: @Dmitry_Kovalov you can try sharing it the data with a notification listener on the listview inner or outer. That should do the trick.

Comment: @LohitRachakonda what do you mean "sharing it the data"?

Comment: @Dmitry_Kovalov submit the animation state to using notification listener

Comment: @LohitRachakonda You can read above why saving the state is impossible task.